# Selenium: how to wait for RichFaces ajax requests to complete

Tags: ajax, jsf, selenium, richfaces, selenium-rc

I use selenium to test a JSF/RichFaces application. The tests randomly fail due to 'Element not found' errors. This is as described in [Selenium: intermittent “element not found” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961044/selenium-intermittent-element-not-found-issues), but it relates only to jQuery ajax calls.

The challenge here is to make the selenium test execution wait for all ajax requests to complete using `selenium.waitForCondition(jsExpression, timeout)`. What is the best jsExpression when using RichFaces ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

I investigated the generated html for the a4j:status. The code below does the job for now, it's better than `wait()` statements, but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
// depends on <a4j:status> present in the page under test
selenium.waitForCondition(          
    "selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById(
    "_viewRoot:status.start\").style.display == 'none'",
    "3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I once found myself in the same situation as you. Additionally, I had a lot of elements that were actually found, but weren't visible - JSF wasn't quick enough to make them visible yet. Also, I got tired of writing `selenium` again and again.

So I sat down and wrote the code below. It waits for all elements to be present on the page and visible before interacting with them (or fails after a timeout). I have since moved to WebDriver, so I don't have the original code, but it was something like this:

```
public static long WAIT = 10000;    // ten seconds

private void waitForElement(String locator) {
    long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + WAIT;
    boolean found;
    do {
        found = selenium.isElementPresent(locator) && selenium.isVisible(locator);
    } while (!found && (targetTime < System.currentTimeMillis()));
    if (!found) {
        throw new SeleniumException("Element " + locator + " not found");
    }
}

public void click(String locator) {
    waitForElement(locator);
    selenium.click(locator);
}

public void type(String locator, String text) {
    waitForElement(locator);
    selenium.type(locator, text);
}
```

As for `waitForCondition()` this should be a code detecting whether an element exists or not:

```
String locator = "id=anything";
String script =
        "var retValue = true;" +
        "try {" +
        "    selenium.browserbot.findElement('" + locator + "');" +
        "} catch(e) {" +
        "    retValue = false;" +
        "}" +
        "retValue;";
selenium.waitForCondition("!!selenium.browserbot.findElement('" + locator + "')", "10000");
selenium.click(locator);
```

and just the plain JavaScript:

```
var retValue = true;
try {
    selenium.browserbot.findElement('" + locator + "');
} catch(e) {
    retValue = false;
}
retValue;
```